# Bayes-Poincaré solution to k-sample tests for comparison and the Behrens-Fisher problem? (XV crosspost)

Tags: probability, statistical-inference, bayesian, hypothesis-testing, bayes-theorem

Given that the Behrens-Fisher problem appears in several places on MSE, I allow myself to signal those posts on Cross Validated:

[Bayes-Poincaré solution to k-sample tests for comparison and the Behrens-Fisher problem?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/419690/bayes-poincar%c3%a9-solution-to-k-sample-tests-for-comparison-and-the-behrens-fisher)

[Bayes-Poincaré solution to the Behrens-Fisher problem 2: calculations for Jeffreys’ priors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/423628/bayes-poincar%c3%a9-solution-to-the-behrens-fisher-problem-2-calculations-for-jeffre)

I propose an alternative solution and I ask whether it is right or wrong.